# RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath() returns wrong route in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I got the following routes:

```
// pennames
routes.MapRoute(
    "pennames", // Route name
    "MyHome/Authors/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Author", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);

// article
routes.MapRoute(
    "article", // Route name
    "MyHome/Articles/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Article", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);

// index
routes.MapRoute(
    "MyHome", // Route name
    "MyHome/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "MyHome", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

I'm trying to add paging functionality to my "MyHome/Articles/" view. The pager is using the following code to get the URL:

```
var virtualPathData = RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath(this.viewContext.RequestContext, pageLinkValueDictionary);

if (virtualPathData != null)
{
    string linkFormat = "<a href=\"{0}\">{1}</a>";
    return String.Format(linkFormat, virtualPathData.VirtualPath, linkText);
}
else
{
    return null;
}
```

The problem is, although I'm running this code from "MyHome/Articles/" page the `GetVirtualPath` always returns the first route "MyHome/Authors/" and completely ignores the prefix "MyHome/Articles/" in the route.

When I use the `ActionLink` it works fine, just not from `GetVirtualPath`.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you had a look at the Route Debugger? http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx It's pretty helpful for figuring out how the routes are being processed.

Comment: Yes i did, it looks fine in the debugger, could it be a bug in the GetVirtualPath or something is wrong with my routes?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply pagination to your MyHome/Articles

You can give a hardcoded path like

yourpath="MyHome/Articles?page=" + page_number;

and each time you have to receive the page parameter from view with that pagination helper available for view or with the <%=Html.ActionLink()%> and pass routes parameter within this.